# WPGraphQL: Custom Post Types query using SLUG as unique identifier returns no data

Tags: wordpress, graphql, apollo, wp-graphql

I've created a Custom Post Type in WordPress named "projects" and now I'm trying to query a single project using the slug as an identifier. In other words, I want the idType to be the SLUG, not ID. I tried the following query but it does not work.

[image]

However, this query works (it's a common query that is using the ID) :

[image]

The query above is not what i'm looking for, but at least i know that my CPT is registered correctly and that my data can be fetched somehow.

**Why I think this is a problem?**
Because I used the same type of query for querying WordPress posts (not custom posts types, just posts) and it works fine. I'm being returned the correct data.

[image]

Any help is appreciated ;) I don't know if i'm missing something with my query, or if custom post types don't work the same way that posts do.

> WPGraphQL version: 1.3.10 Other WordPress plugins installed: Advanced
> Custom Fields, Custom Post Type UI

Answer (score 1):

Set the `idType` to `URI`. Here's an example, querying a page (it's the same for other post types as well):

[image]

NOTE: the GraphiQL IDE has some nice auto-completions and drop-downs to show the available options:

[image]

My understanding is the `idType:SLUG` option is not available when your custom post type is hierarchical since the slug would not be a unique identifier at that point.

Comment: i don't want to use URI, as i need to pass the slug as a props to my component (to generate a named route). the issue i mentioned has been fixed recently, this was a bug in the core-plugin as you'll be able to read here:
https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/pull/2132

Comment: @victorcngo interesting. The URI option works fine to filter hierarchical post types by slug though so that may be why I've not ran into this myself.

Comment: Looking at the PR more closely, I see that Jason mentions needing to have public => true on your post type definition. I've had to do that as well in order to make the filter by URI (slug/permalink) work.

Comment: thank you for your help and your answer though! look like it's fixed and clean now ;)

Comment: @victorcngo 's fix worked for me. I was able to query by `SLUG` after setting `'hierarchical' => false` in my `register_post_type`.